# Create session via API Token sets an expired cookie

Tags: api, authentication, session, token, onelogin

I am trying to [create a session via an API token](https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-via-token) .

The request is sent **successfully**, I'm getting 3 cookies in the response, but their **expiry date is the same as the time at which the request was sent**, which invalidates them instantly.

For example, if the request is sent successfully on **20 April 2020, 00:24:29** this is the response:

```
Set-Cookie: persistent=XXXX; path=/; expires=Thu, 19-Mar-2020 00:24:30 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: onelogin.com_user=XXX; domain=.onelogin.com; path=/; expires=Mon, 20-Apr-2020 00:24:30 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: sub_session_onelogin.com=XXXXXXX; path=/; secure; HttpOnly
```

The **second cookie** that creates the session for using it on Onelogin **is already expired**.

*Is there anything that is being done wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.*

***I am using HTTPS.***

Comment: the OneLogin API team has been made aware of your inquiry and a OneLogin developer will be reviewing your inquiry and will get back to you when time permits in regards to your API questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial API request to get the session token (note, not cookie) is a backend call from the app to the OneLogin API and so it is not visible in user browser, but you can see that that API call returns the JWT token with a 2 minute timeout to a customer app. You can navigate to https://jwt.io/ and click Debugger for verification. There will be an expiration area on the right side and you can hover over this to see the expiration. There is always a 2 minute timeout associated with it.

It is then the responsibility of your app to direct the user's browser to send the token in a HTTP payload to OneLogin at "/session_via_api_token", so as to provide a session cookie to the browser. You can use the SAML Tracer extension in your browser to capture a SAML trace to verify, by viewing the "HTTP" tab of the POST line for "session_via_api_token". Note: 3 cookies are set, of which 2 are persistent and are immediately set to expire - so they serve no purpose. So don't stress the fact that those 2 cookies are expired as it's not relevant. The key cookie is "subsession_onelogin.com" which is a session cookie and so has no expiry time in it. It is used to track session timeout.

If the user then attempts to get access to a OneLogin resource then it includes the new "subsession_onelogin.com" cookie and so is considered authenticated. OneLogin then issues an updated version of that cookie, which you can see in the SAML Trace on the GET line for the "sub_session.onelogin.com" Set-Cookie area.

It appears that the way the CORS method works for this API is slightly different than the form post method, and the API team has been made aware, as the Dev article will likely be updated to state that the form post method is suggested.

In addition, per my testing it appears that some browsers react differently, so testing other browsers would certainly shed more light. That is browser specific and as such wouldn't be related to the API calls. With the Create Session request on Safari when the default setting of "Prevent Cross Site Cookie Tracking" is enabled I have noticed that the cookies are returned as expected but the browser refuses to accept them. There is no warning or error in the browser console. It's unknown why Safari does this and can't find any documentation about it so that's a browser specific issue out of our control.

Browsers are making it harder so our API team will probably update our best practice guidelines in the coming months to say to use the form post redirect rather than CORS. The form post method should work for any and all browsers as they handle it different than the CORS method.

The first link in the API docs is https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-via-token and the second link to use it https://developers.onelogin.com/api-docs/1/login-page/create-session-login-token. You can then use https://jwt.io/ and click Debugger for verification. It's working properly with a 2 minute expiry which is correct. The key cookie is "subsession_onelogin.com" which is a session cookie and so has no expiry time in it as it is used to track session timeout.

In my tests I have verified that there is definitely a 2-minute lifetime, which is exactly how it should work. In my example tests it shows that the API response is claiming expiry at 16:19:04, which matches the jwt.io decoder (that site is useful for this). The 2nd part of the test returned the headers DATE parameter which shows the time of issue was 16:17:04; i.e. a 2 minutes before expiry. This is correct.

I imagine the problem you are having is caused by how your app directs the user's browser to invoke the "/session_via_api_token" call - if the app uses CORS then obviously you would need to include the relevant header. However, it appears that even with that header, some browsers will not send the CORS request (presumably due to browser security settings) and so the session never gets established. At least that is what I can see when using the sample custom login page in testing. Note: The first call is a REST API call (i.e. what Postman is good for), but the 2nd request is a regular browser request.

Comment: I have successfully authenticated a user using the flow you have described here. When the user go to some other onelogin app, they get automatcally logged in. But, how to support the automatic login from the 3rd part app to my app ? I do not see any documentation related to that.